# Server Scanning Returning Patch Data as Very Old and Old

Tags: powershell

Just need Clarification about this code output.
Script output upon running still is saying that there is still very old patches still remaining on servers but we already verified that the server is already patched.

**REQUIREMENTS**

- Active Directory module
- WinRM enabled on target machines (for WMI)
- Local administrator on target machines
- NB. Some WMI scans do not work on all operating systems (particularly older ones)

**AUDIT CRITERIA**

- Complete a discovery scan of windows update history
- Collect a good sized random sample from both Servers and Computers (ensure to rename output file, to avoid overwriting)
- Make a note of any Warnings for 'Old' or 'Very Old' events

```
    $Domain = $(get-addomain).dnsroot
    $Log = "C:\temp\Audit\$Domain Update History $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv"

    $Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -LIKE "*server*" -AND Enabled -eq $TRUE} -Property Name  
    #$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -NOTLIKE "*server*" -AND Enabled -eq $TRUE} -Property Name
    $Computers = Get-Random -InputObject $Computers -Count 100

    $obj=@()
    $Data = @()
    $Events = 10  # <- Events to collect per machine

    $Old = (get-date).AddDays(-14)
    $OldCount = 0
    $VeryOld = (get-date).AddDays(-30)
    $VeryOldCount = 0

    foreach ($Computer in $Computers.name) {

        if(!(Test-Connection -Cn $Computer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet)){
            write-host "WARNING: $Computer not accessible" -f yellow
        }
        else {
            try{
                write-host "Working on $Computer"

                $Session = [activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session",$Computer))
                $Searcher= $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
                $History = $Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $Events)

                $ComputerCount++

                Foreach($Entry in $History | ?{$_.Title -NOTLIKE "*Defender*"}) {
                    $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
                    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Computer" -Value $Computer
                    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Date" -Value $Entry.Date
                    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Description" -Value $Entry.Title

                    $EventCount++
                    if ($Entry.Date -le $VeryOld){
                        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Age" -Value "Very Old"
                        $VeryOldCount++
                    }
                    elseif ($Entry.Date -le $Old){
                        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Age" -Value "Old"
                        $OldCount++
                    }
                    else{
                        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Age" -Value "Recent"
                        $RecentCount++
                    }

                    $Data += $obj
                }
            }
            catch{
                write-host "WARNING: $Computer not accessible" -foregroundcolor yellow
            }
        }
    }

    $Data | sort-object -property Computer,Date -descending | Export-Csv $Log -notype

    write-host ""
    write-host "There were $EventCount Windows Update events listed from $ComputerCount computers"
    write-host "$RecentCount events are recent"
    write-host "$OldCount events are old" -foregroundcolor yellow
    write-host "$VeryOldCount events are very old" -foregroundcolor red
    write-host ""
    write-host "Log Export Complete to $Log"
```

Just need an insight of what this codes returns as the server has already been restarted and still returns data dating back to July and August.

Comment: I assume this isn;t your code? According to the AUDIT CRITERIA notes it looks like you have to initiate a discovery scan for the information to update

Comment: yes not our code. I just need a breakdown if it produces output that is =veryold will is it a flaw in out patch system or no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your code does:

You get 100 random Servers (`$Computers = Get-Random -InputObject $Computers -Count 100`)
and Query them for their last 10 Events (`$History = $Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $Events)`). If they aren't from the Defender they are seperated by age of recent, old (14 Days) and very old (30 Days).

Very old just means that those machines had less than 10 events in the last 30 days. If you get 1 patch event yesterday and the rest is 30 days old this server will count 9 in `$VeryOldCount`. But the Server may still be up to date.

Comment: I somehow partly get it so meaning they wont hold us accountable if output produces veryold count = 9 example. we just need to make sure service is uptodate.

Comment: The log they create will contain the computername, the date and the title of the events. They should be able to see that there have been recent updates (if there are). I assume it would be a problem if a computer has no recent event at all.

Comment: I see thanks for the insight. sorry if I am a bit slow. So, It just reflects patch events for one example server or two. and marks it as very old or old, not really negative If I am correct. (so I can explain to the management the case) May I ask why if i run the script again why does it return the same servers when it should just be random.

Comment: `Get-Random -InputObject $Computers -Count 100` returns up to 100 servers of those he found in your AD (`Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -LIKE "*server*" ...`) the question is howmuch servers you have :)

Comment: we have numerous servers. it keeps on returning both when i rerun the script daily.

Comment: Execute this (one line) to get the names and the count of the servers he found:`$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -LIKE "*server*" -AND Enabled -eq $TRUE} -Property Name;$Computers.name;"count = ";$Computers.Count `